# Laravel Echo Server can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403

Tags: laravel, sockets, authentication, vuejs2, laravel-echo

I got `laravel-echo-server` and `Laravel 5` application with `vuejs`, and I'm trying to connect front end to back end via sockets.

I've managed to connect everything together via `Echo.channel()` method, however it will not subscribe with `Echo.private()`

This is what I got so far :

Once the page loads I call :

I initilise the `Echo` via

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
broadcaster: 'socket.io',
host: window.location.hostname + ':6001',
csrfToken : Laravel.csrfToken,
auth : {
    headers : {
        Authorization : "Bearer b6f96a6e99e90dzzzzzzz"
    }
}
```

});

Then I create a new event via `vue resourse`

```
Vue.http.get('/api/errors/get');
```

This fires laravel `event(new \App\Events\ErrorsEvent());` event

Which Broadcasts the event privately via

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('errors');
}
```

At this point `laravel-echo-server` responds with

```
Channel: private-errors
Event: App\Events\ErrorsEvent
CHANNEL private-errors
```

Then i try to subscribe to the channel with echo by running

```
Echo.private('errors')
           .listen('ErrorsEvent', (e) => {
           this.errors = e.errors;
        console.log(e);
       });
```

At which `laravel-echo-server` responds with

```
[14:47:31] - xxxxxxxxxxxxxx could not be authenticated to private-errors

Client can not be authenticated, got HTTP status 403
```

Does anybody know if I'm missing something here?

**EDIT**

This is my `BroadcastServiceProvider`

```
public function boot(Request $request)
{

    Broadcast::routes();
    /*
     * Authenticate the user's personal channel...
     */
    Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) {
        return (int) $user->id === (int) $userId;
    });
}
```

Also, I've discovered that if I try to subscribe to

```
Echo.private('App.User.2')
       .listen('ErrorsEvent', (e) => {
       this.errors = e.errors;
    console.log(e);
   });
```

It connects and everything is ok, however it still refuses to connect with the `errors` channel

Comment: Please show your broadcast routes and how you're authenticating the user instance.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue, did you ever resolve this? Also, where do you get your auth Bearer code from?

Comment: The issue was within the auth bearer. If i remember correctly before you start echo server, you need to generate a client ID. This will create appId and & key, which you use as auth bearer.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was that I hadn't noticed there are *two* `BroadcastServiceProvider::class` entries in app/config.php

I had only checked the first one. Once I uncommented `App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class` I didn't need to specify the bearer token.

I believe the reason you couldn't connect on the `errors` channel in your above config is that you need to change your call in your BroadcastServiceProvider (or `routes/channels.php`) to

```
Broadcast::channel('errors', function ($user) {
        return true; //replace with suitable auth check here
});
```